# How to fix unwanted character acceleration in a Pygame game?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I made a game where a character has to get coins on a 2D map (when you get a coin, it respawns on a random place), while running away form a spongebob-type character who moves randomly. If you touch the spongebob, you die.

The problem I am having is that my character sometimes goes slow, but then sometimes randomly goes fast when I am controlling it with my arrow keys. My changing in the values in the code is constant, so can someone explain to me this doesn't work?
[Github Link](https://github.com/StreetFighterLan123/Survive_the_spongey_boi)

Here is the code if you don't want to open the link:

```py
import pygame
import random
import math
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Survive the Spongey Boi")

#Sounds
game_over_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Game_Over.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("background.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

#Score
coins_collected = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
#coinfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
#Positions of the text.
coin_textX = 10
coin_textY = 10

def show_coin_score(x,y):
    coins_text = font.render("Coins: " + str(coins_collected), True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(coins_text, (x,y))

#Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('monster.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0

#Spongebob
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('sponge.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0,735)
enemyY = random.randint(10,400)
enemyX_change = 0
enemyY_change = 0

#Coin
coinImg = pygame.image.load('coin.png')
coinX = random.randint(0,735)
coinY = random.randint(0,535)

#Font for Game Over
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

def enemy(x,y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x,y))

def coin(x,y):
    screen.blit(coinImg, (x,y))

def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, playerX, playerY):
    #Distance formula in Python
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - playerX,2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - playerY,2))) 
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

def coin_collision(coinX, coinY, playerX, playerY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(coinX - playerX,2)) + (math.pow(coinY - playerY,2))) 
    if distance < 29:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200,250))

#Game loop
running = True

while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,206))
    #Do the for loop here.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #Do the keydown
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change

    enemyX += enemyX_change
    enemyY += enemyY_change
    #Boundaries
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX > 736:
        playerX = 736
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY > 536:
        playerY = 536

    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX = 0
    elif enemyX > 736:
        enemyX = 736
    if enemyY <= 0:
        enemyY = 0
    elif enemyY > 536:
        enemyY = 536

    if isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, playerX, playerY):
        game_over_text()
        playerX = 10000
        enemyX = 10000
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(game_over_sound)
        time.sleep(3.5)
        break
    if coin_collision(coinX, coinY, playerX, playerY):
        coins_collected += 1
        #time.sleep(0.00001)
        coinX = random.randint(0,735)
        coinY = random.randint(0,535)
    #CHANGE THIS LATER
    enemyX_change = random.randint(-15,15)
    enemyY_change = random.randint(-15,15)

    #score_value = score_value//1

    show_coin_score(coin_textX, coin_textY)
    coin(coinX, coinY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `acceleration is the rate of change of the velocity of an object with respect to time` If you want to competently manage acceleration in your game, you should implement both proper velocity, and a proper timekeeping system.  See [vector2](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and [clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice game! The issue seems to be cause, because you use the `KEYDOW` and `KEYUP` event. That may lead to ans issue when you change the direction between left and right respectively up and down, because the movement is canceled in on `KEYUP`.

I recommend to use the [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) to get the current states of the key. Set `playerX_change` respectively `playerY_change` dependent on the state of the keys:

```py
while running:
    # [...]    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    playerX_change, playerY_change = 0, 0
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX_change -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX_change += 2
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerY_change -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerY_change += 2
```

---

Side note, use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to simplify the limitation to the bounderys:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    #Boundaries
    playerX = max(0, min(736, playerX))
    playerY = max(0, min(536, playerY))
    enemyX  = max(0, min(736, enemyX))
    enemyY  = max(0, min(536, enemyY))
```